# Odoo 9 Set default datetime at a specific hour

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, odoo, odoo-9

I found how to do that in old API v7 in `https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/set-default-datetime-at-a-specific-hour-35591`:

```
_defaults = {
    'date_start': lambda self,cr,uid,context=None: fields.date.context_today(self,cr,uid,context) + " 09:00:00"
}
```

But I need to reuse it to new API. I tried:

```
   'date_from' = fields.Datetime('Date From', required=True, default= lambda self:self.date + " 09:00:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
date_from = fields.Datetime('Date From', required=True, default=fields.Datetime.now)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I need specific hour.For example yy/mm/dd 09:00:00 and only then when I click on calendar to select the date.

Comment: By giving datetime.now().replace(hour=9, minute=0)  will solve your problem but while applying it in odoo gives wrong time.   Please try this code                                                                                       **date_order = fields.Datetime('Order Date', required=True, select=True, copy=False,
                                default=datetime.now().replace(hour=3, minute=30))**